# How to set the jump mode of a single page2

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
    const RootStack2 = createStackNavigator({

    Main: {
         screen: HomeScreen, 
      },
    MyModal: {
          screen: ModalScreen, 
     },
    Detail:{
         screen: DetailScreen, 
     }

    },{
        //global setting
        mode:"modal"   
    });
```

It's like a global setting. I want to jump to `mymodal` and use the model mode. Jump to the `card mode of detail`

I use react-navigation@3.13

Comment: add more details to your question.. what you done so far and what do you want to do and if there's any issues

Comment: You [asked this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596846/how-to-set-the-jump-mode-of-a-single-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set `mode` prop for each screen separately. What you can do is specify the transition animation specs for each screen using `transitionSpec` in `navigationOptions`.

`MyModal: {screen: ModalScreen, navigationOptions: { transitionSpec: {...} } }`

Now, in `transitionSpec`, you can either specify the animations yourself, or use pre-made configs like `FadeInFromBottomAndroidSpec` and `TransitionIOSSpec`, which are, I believe, `card` and `modal` modes respectively.

```
transitionSpec: {
  open: TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
  close: TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#pre-made-configs). Hope this helps.